# God cards are allowed?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I know there that the anime version of God cards are: overpowered, effects are not unclearly specified in the card text, and illegal to play in tournaments and private matches.

My question is about the legal version. They can be normally played in tournaments and private matches? or just private matches? I'm confused because I don't see these cards included in the [official forbidden/limited list](https://www.yugioh-card.com/oc/limited/).

Also, in private matches, do I need to inform the opponent BEFORE the match that I'm using legal version of God card (so he doesn't cry later), or it's totally fine/legal to surprise him (LOL)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a card is not on the Forbidden/Limited list, and the card does not have the text "This card cannot be used in a Duel" printed on it (as is the case with a few novelty cards, like the legendary collection 1 god cards) then the card is legal.

In private matches, there is no need to inform your opponent of your deck's contents, provided the deck adheres to deckbuilding rules.

Answer (score 3):

All of the non-illegal monster cards which have a Divine attribute are currently set at unlimited, meaning you can play 3 of them in a deck with no limitations.

Source: https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_DIVINE_monsters

None of the cards listed have limitations. I'm not sure how you came to the conclusion that they might have one since they are widely seen as bad cards in competitive play.